# Replace elements in an array depending on their value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with nested arrays inside. Each array has an element called CBSA which has a five digit number as its value. In a different array, I have the five digit number as keys, and the values corresponding to them as their values. I want to loop thru the nested array and replace the five digit value with their corresponding values from the second array. For example:

```
$array = array(array(CBSA => 12345),
               array(CBSA => 98765),
               array(CBSA => 56789));
```

And in another array I have this:

```
$array2 = array(12345 => "George Washington",
                56789=> "Barack Obama",
                98765=> "Thomas Jefferson");
```

I want to find the values in each nested array and replace it with the corresponding string in the second array.

So that the first array will become:

```
$array = array(array(CBSA=>"George Washington"), 
               array(CBSA=>"Thomas Jefferson"), 
               array(CBSA => "Barack Obama"));
```

Comment: If you want only the value like George Washington, Thomas Jefferson and Barack Obama so I develop the program to get the value.

Comment: So you want keys or values or both of them.

Comment: You want to print keys or values or both of them?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to loop through your first array, then just assign it the corresponding value from the second array... something like this

```
$results = array();

foreach($array as $key => $cbsa) {
    if (isset($array2[$cbsa['CBSA']])) {
        $array[$key]['CBSA'] = 
        $results[] = array('CBSA' => $array2[$cbsa['CBSA']]);
    }
}
```

As a full working example using your initial code, and the above loop, this gives the desired output:

```
<?php

$array = array(array('CBSA' => 12345),
               array('CBSA' => 98765),
               array('CBSA' => 56789));

$array2 = array(12345 => "George Washington",
                56789=> "Barack Obama",
                98765=> "Thomas Jefferson");

$results = array();

foreach($array as $key => $cbsa) {
    if (isset($array2[$cbsa['CBSA']])) {
        $results[] = array('CBSA' => $array2[$cbsa['CBSA']]);
    }
}
echo('<pre>');
print_r($results);
```

Comment: The thing is that the second array is just an array of pairs of numbers and strings, and the first array's numbers are not in the same order as the second one's. I need to be able to match up the right number with its pair in the second array and replace it with the corresponding string.

Comment: I've copied full working code into the answer that is giving me the desired results. If you are still getting undefined offset errors, it seems your data is missmatching, if this is the case let me know and I'll modify to cater for this

Comment: It works, when I print_r the array, it does do the job, but for some reason, I'm also getting a few hundred of these: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 31080 in... And I'm not sure why.

Comment: Fairly certain if you look up those IDs, they wont exist in your second array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to cater for ID's that don't exist in the second array, this should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
Demo: https://eval.in/84567

```
$array = array(array('CBSA' => '12345'), array('CBSA' => '98765'), array('CBSA' => '56789'));
$array2 = array('12345' => "George Washington", '56789'=> "Barack Obama", '98765'=> "Thomas Jefferson");
$result = array();
foreach($array as $arr){
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    array_push($result,array($key => $array2[$val]));
}
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Using two foreach loops are not so optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with only one foreach loop

```
 $array = array(array(CBSA => 12345),
               array(CBSA => 98765),
               array(CBSA => 56789));

 $array2 = array(12345 => "George Washington",
                56789=> "Barack Obama",
                98765=> "Thomas Jefferson");

 $newArray  = array();

 foreach($array as $key => $value) {
      $newArray[] = array('CBSA' => $array2[$value['CBSA']]);
 }

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: using static CBSA key is not also a good solution.Key may be changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrays = array(
        array("CBSA" => 12345),
        array("CBSA" => 98765),
        array("CBSA" => 56789)
    );
$array2 = array(
        12345 => "George Washington",
        56789 => "Barack Obama",
        98765 => "Thomas Jefferson"
    );
/****** Code block ********/
array_walk($arrays, function(&$array) use ($array2)
{
    $arr = array_values($array);
    if(@$array2[$arr[0]]) // $arr[0] contains numeric value
    {
        $key = array_search($arr[0], $array); // contains CBSA
        $array[$key] = $array2[$arr[0]];
    }
});
print_r($arrays);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CBSA] => George Washington
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CBSA] => Thomas Jefferson
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CBSA] => Barack Obama
        )

)
```