# Replacing elements in an array without knowing what the original value will be / PHP

Tags: php, arrays, replace, preg-replace

I have a csv which has been converted into multiple arrays . One element of the array contains shoe sizes as a string . These sizes can be any group of numbers from 2 to 16 .

I have exploded the string to place each size in an element of it's own so then I can implode it too have the pipe character in between each shoe size . Before I implode the array I want to change the shoe sizes from from just a number to UK, US, and EU sizes, eg 2 becomes UK2/US6/EU36  3 becomes UK3/US7/EU37 etc...

I have looked at preg repalce preg match array splice but the problem I have is that the first element in the array  is not always the same size . it can start at any shoe size depending on the stock . Also sizes can be missed out of the order .

I have looked at this solution but not sure if it is the best way to do it [Replace elements in an array depending on their value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865869/replace-elements-in-an-array-depending-on-their-value)

```
 $exp = explode(" ", $data[12]);
print_r($exp); 

//change form size into UK/US/EU sizes ?   

//add pipe character bewtween size and return to string
$imp = implode("|", $exp);

$model = str_replace("Model: ", "", $data[13]);

$brand = str_replace("Manufactured by: ", "", $data[14]);

// This is where you build your array output
$outputData = array($data[5], $data[6], $data[7], $data[15], $data[16], $data[21]= $model, $data[22]= $imp, $data[23]= $brand);
```

This is what i want to be able to do

Original Code after explode

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 9
)
```

Change to this

```
Array
(
    [0] => UK2/US5/EU35
    [1] => UK3/US6/EU36
    [2] => UK4/US7/EU37
    [3] => UK5/US8/EU38
    [4] => UK6/US9/EUR39
    [5] => UK7/US10/EU40
    [6] => UK8/US11/EU41
    [7] => UK9/US12/EUR42
)
```

then i can implode .

Comment: I understand that the values of the original code is of the UK size. The problem is: how do you convert UK size into US size / EU size? Do you have some sort of conversion table or formular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just go through each array element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and change it as you want it:

```
<?php

    $exp = array_map(function($v){
        return "UK" . $v . "/US" . ($v + 3) . "/EU" . ($v + 33);
    }, $exp);

    print_r($exp);

?>
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks alot, Never even crossed my mind to look at the values of the sizes like that .

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this simple?

```
foreach($exp as &$v) {
    $v = 'UK'.$v.'/US'.($v+3).'/EU'.($v+33);
}
```

Comment: *Could it be this simple?* No, because this will not work as you think it does :) (hint: -> **()**)